# Error while pushing a new project to GitHub

Tags: eclipse, git, github

I have created a new project and have also create a new repository on GitHub. I want to push that project to my GitHub repository using the Eclipse GitHub plugin.

I have entered my username and password correctly.
But when I tried to create a new remote I was getting the following error.

[image: error: can't connect to any repository: not authorized]

Comment: And? It still doesn't work?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk No It didn't worked.

Comment: I had configured the remote but when I tried to push my project then I got this error.